# Initial conditions set up for a Schwarzschild Black hole

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I intend to perform Ray tracing around a Schwarzschild black hole. The whole system is expressed in spherical polar coordinates with the black hole placed at the origin. I require 8 initial conditions to numerically solve the four 2nd order geodesic equations that come about. Namely, $$(t(0),r(0),\theta(0),\phi(0),t'(0),r'(0),\theta'(0),\phi'(0)).$$ I can set $t(0) = 0 $ for all rays since that means that I am shooting all the rays at the same time which is perfectly okay. $(r(0),\theta(0),\phi(0))$ correspond to the pixel positions(Red dots) on the 2D image plane that I have. Their position vectors are denoted by $\bf{P_B}$ which are expressed in spherical coordinates relative to the origin. I am able to compute these vectors. My main issue is computing the vectors $$P_B' = (t'(0),r'(0),\theta'(0),\phi'(0)).$$

$\bf{U_0}$ are unit vectors that give the direction of the pixel relative to the **observer**. I can compute these but in cartesian coordinates. I thought I could convert them to spherical coordinates and use them as the initial conditions but that does not work. Another thing that I need to look out for is that this condition always needs to be satisfied, $ g_{i j } \bf{P_{B}^{i}}' \bf{P_{B}^{j}}' = 0$. Where $g_{i j }$ is the metric tensor. How can I obtain $\bf{P_B}'$?

[image]

Comment: You can either take parallel rays projected to a flat screen like they did [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02063) or collect the rays as with a pinhole camera as in [here](http://raytracer.yukterez.net), but the parallel rays to the flat screen are only good if the observer is far away where space is almost flat, otherwise the screen distortion makes it unnecessarily complicated. If you want to go close or inside, the pinhole method is better. To compare your results use a source like [this](http://tinyurl.com/4z4zyu4m) to make sure everything is as it should be.